# confused with shared folders and ACL

Tags: sharing, acl

I have 2 ubuntu machines (ubuntu1 and ubuntu2). Ubuntu1 shares folder /opt/share and i've created **testuser** specifically to rwx:

```
setfacl -Rm u:testuser:rwx .
```

Ubuntu2 mounts it on /mnt/ubuntu1

```
mount -t cifs -o user=testuser,password=thepassword //ubuntu1/share1 /mnt/ubuntu1
```

I can see the shared folder on the Ubuntu2 and list the files init

```
ls -lh
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 root root 0 Nov  3 00:31 aginova
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 root root 0 Nov  3 00:31 brother
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 root root 0 Nov  3 00:31 dizcoisas
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 root root 0 Nov  3 00:31 equipamentos
```

This is where it starts to get confusing:
Testing the share on a windows machine, i authenticate with testuser,thepassword and i'm able to rwx, but on the Ubuntu2 machine, although the share is mounted with the same user, i get "Permission denied" when trying to write.

looking at the access lists i can see another user having permission in this folder that i never setup ( ??? )

```
root@ubuntu2:/mnt/share1# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:siemens:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

And if i try to setfacl like i did in ubuntu2 it returns an error basically saying testuser does not exist or "Permission denied" .

```
root@ubuntu2:/mnt/ubuntu1# sudo setfacl -bR .
setfacl: .: Permission denied
setfacl: ./aginova: Permission denied
setfacl: ./equipamentos: Permission denied
setfacl: ./dizcoisas: Permission denied
setfacl: ./brother: Permission denied
root@ubuntu2:/mnt/ubuntu# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:siemens:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x

root@ubuntu2:/mtn/ubuntu1# sudo setfacl -Rm u:testuser:rwx /mnt/ubuntu1/setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 3
```

So, why does the share mount works with rwx in windows but only with r-- in ubuntu2 ?

Answer (score 0):

the only way i got this working was by applying this on machine ubuntu1

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/share
```

then set "valid users" like this in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[share]
...
valid users = testuser
```

this way only specified users can access the share anyways so no real need to set ACL for this case since the user is supposed to have rwx anyway